# Numpy Sum when each array has a specific value

Tags: python, numpy

```
x1 = np.array([0,  1,  0,  1,  0, 1, 0, 1, 1,  1])
y = np.array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1])
```

I know with these 2 arrays you can sum up the amount of times exact indicies are equal with numpy in this line of code.

```
np.sum(x1 == y)
```

but is there a way to sum up each time the same index equals a specific value on each array such as

```
np.sum(x1 == 1 && y == -1)
```

Unfortunately this line of code doesn't run, but if it worked the result should be 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just have to use a single `&` and add some parentheses:

`np.sum((x1 == 1) & (y == -1))`

This gives 3 as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Besides `a & b` in numpy, you may also use `logical_and`, just FYI.

```
np.sum(np.logical_and((x1 == 1), (y == -1)))
```